# Condition changes in ngClass but class is not updated

Tags: css, angular

I'm trying to hide and show the div on click event of icon.for that I am using ngClass with condition.When variable in condition changes the class remains same ,it's not updating the class.

//html

```
<div class="column  icon">
    <mat-icon (click)="onIconClick()" id="icon" class="column" [ngStyle]="showpanel ? {'color':'#4ac2f7'}:''">filter_list</mat-icon>
</div>
```

//hide and show the div

```
<div class="search-box-container" id="filter-tab" [ngClass]="'showpanel' ? 'show' : 'hidden'">
</div>
```

//onclick icon .ts code

```
onIconClick() {
    if (this.showpanel) {
      this.showpanel = false;
    } else {
      this.showpanel = true;
    }
    console.log(this.showpanel);
}
```

Comment: can you show your css code.

Answer (score 2):

Remove Condition(showpanel) single quote

Try this:

```
<div class="search-box-container" id="filter-tab" [ngClass]="showpanel ? 'show' : 'hidden'">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<button (click)="showpanel= !showpanel" id="icon" class="column" [ngStyle]="showpanel ? {'color':'#4ac2f7'}:''">filter_list</button>

 <div class="search-box-container" id="filter-tab" [ngClass]="showpanel ? 'show' : 'hidden'">
      filter-tab
 </div>
```

Css

```
.show {
     display: block;
    }

    .hidden {
      display: none;
    }
```

without Function even you can do the same thing.

> [Stackblitz link here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n856vx)

and if you want function to do the same then

```
onIconClick() {
this.showpanel =! this.showpanel;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This `[ngClass]="'showpanel' ? 'show' : 'hidden'"` pattern is taking your `showpanel` as a string, so it will always evaluated as `true` and return `'show'` class. Remove the **`single quote mark`** and it shall evaluate correctly

Answer (score 0):

You have not added CSS in your question. Although, I checked your code. You only need to remove quotes from showpanel.
Please see below code -

In app.component.html

```
 <button (click)="onIconClick()" id="icon" class="column" [ngStyle]="showpanel ? {'color':'#4ac2f7'}:''">filter_list</button>

 <div class="search-box-container" id="filter-tab" [ngClass]="showpanel ? 'show' : 'hidden'">
      filter-tab
 </div>
```

In your aap.component.ts

```
showpanel = false;
onIconClick() {
  if (this.showpanel) {
    this.showpanel = false;
  } else {
    this.showpanel = true;
  }
  console.log(this.showpanel);
}
```

In your app.component.css

```
.show {
 display: block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Replace 'div' with 'mat-icon'

Also, you can check the working example here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xsvxd6